# Need to fetch a property based on iteration over an array with respect to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with the following format. Each object has got few properties and also  an array. I have to fetch a property if a key is present in the array.

Consider the below object: When I give key as 7 it should return me 'xyz'. If key is 3 it should give me 'abc'

```
[
  {
    val : 'abc',
    arr : [1,2,3,4]
  },

  {
    val: 'xyz',
    arr : [7,8,9]
  }
]
```

Comment: please add what does not work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us that as well

Comment: What if there are multiple objects whereby the `arr` contains 7 as well?

Comment: Just for a demo, values inside array are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Use find of the main array and check if the `arr` of that object `includes()` the given key. return the `val` property of the found object.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    val : 'abc',
    arr : [1,2,3,4]
  },

  {
    val: 'xyz',
    arr : [7,8,9]
  }
]

const getVal = (arr,key) => (arr.find(x => x.arr.includes(key)) || {}).val;

console.log(getVal(arr,3))
console.log(getVal(arr,7))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the object which meets the condition whereby the element (7) exists in the array. Within the callback function for `Array.some()`, you can use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the element (7), exists in the `arr` property itself:

```js
const data = [
  {
    val : 'abc',
    arr : [1,2,3,4]
  },

  {
    val: 'xyz',
    arr : [7,8,9]
  }
]

const res = data.filter(obj => obj.arr.includes(7))[0].val;
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The code will throw error if no `arr` of any object will not contain the given key.

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks for the reminder. In that case, `[0].val` should be on a separate statement, and should only run if the array isn't empty?

Comment: You can either store the result of `filter()[0]` in a variable and then use ternary operator to return a value. Or either use `|| {}`. Like `(data.filter(obj => obj.arr.includes(7))[0] || {}).val`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
var x = [{
        val: 'abc',
        arr: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },

    {
        val: 'xyz',
        arr: [7, 8, 9]
    }
];
var test = function(data, key) {
    for (let i of x) {
        if (i.arr.indexOf(key) >= 0)
            return i.val;
    }
}

// example

console.log(test(x,9));
```

Comment: `for (i of x)` here you are declaring a global variable. Use `let` before `i`. And also answers like **try this** are not encouraged you should explain what you are doing in code.